# Leading eigenvalue and Leontief inverse

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, economics

Is it possible to get a Leontief inverse matrix $(I-C)^{-1}=I+C+C^2+....$ not equal to $I$ when the leading eigenvalue of matrix $C$, meaning the maximum of absolute eigenvalues, is zero?

I am doing an empirical research and this keeps happening in the code, which I am pretty skeptical about. The $C$ in my case is the partial correlation matrix of some time series.

Comment: yes -- e.g. let $C$ be strictly upper triangular

Comment: I see, makes sense, but checked and they are not upper triangular. Could you elaborate more on what the cases would be or why we would have any matrix other than $I$? I want to understand the reason of this in general. @user8675309

Comment: evidently you are working over complex numbers and all eigenvalues of $C$ are zero so it is *nilpotent* and similar to a strictly upper triangular matrix